# How to test my application with the Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

While an application for Facebook is in development, Facebook and Instagram webhooks do not allow sending real data from a page that has received a notification, and to do so you must use the dashboard provided by Facebook to send test content.

However, without the real test data I have no way to test whether my application will be able to handle real data, as the identifiers sent (posts id, comments id  and users id) are fake and do not exist, so I cannot test:

- Get user information from Facebook or Instagram
- Send a reply to a comment on a Facebook or Instagram post

Is there any way I can perform these tests bidirectionally (Fb (IG)-> my app / my app -> Fb (IG))